# Commerce product slug creates duplicates - can they also be autogenerated?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, slug

The slug for products is generated from the Title, for example in my case "Green Shirt". Seems like these are not unique, and if I create a product later on, also called "Green Shirt", they both get "green-shirt" as slug, and causing problem when viewing the products in a template.

Why isn't this creating unique slugs like for Entries?

And I would rather have the slug autogenerated, like the option for SKU. Is this possible?
Have seen threads about this, but has anyone made a solution yet?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you set a **Product URI Format** in Commerce → System settings → Product Types → your product type?

Comment: Product URI is set to "produkt/{id}"

Comment: Can you try `produkt/{slug}`?